# User Cannot login after changing AD properties

Tags: active-directory, forms-authentication

I am having a strange issue with my FBA authetication.
I have a SharePoint site configured to use FBA with AD server. Recently I changed properties for few AD accounts. After that those users are not able to login to the SharePoint site. It simply says invalid password.
The WFE is logging an error "An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The security token username and password could not be validated.." whenever these users try to login. For all others it works perfectly.

here is the powershell I used to update the AD user account

```
if($state){
            Set-ADUser -Identity $uName -State $state
        }
```

I don't understand what is going wrong. Does this mean the "Set-ADUser" command corrupted the user accounts?

**[UPDATE]**

Found the problem but I do not know how to solve it. In the script mistakenly I added "-l" option. With this option the command corrupts the user account. Is there any way I can recover it?

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $uName -State $state -l $city
```

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: did you try restarting your Token service application pool ?

Comment: Yes, I did that. But not working. In fact I have 2 farms sharing the same AD. Issue is there on both servers. Thats why I suspect that the powershell script that I ran might have corrupted the user account, but not sure

Comment: Did you try this on prod ? I think it takes AD at least a day to cycle thru

Comment: I ran the script today and immediately the users started seeing login issue. So you mean I have to wait for one day? Why it is saying password incorrect? I have not changed the password.

Comment: Is "-l" short form of "-LogonWorkstations"? I cannot find "-l" at MSDN(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx)

Comment: Yes. That was the issue. I was able to fix it now. Thank you very much Mark. Can you put this as answer?

Answer (score 0):

As Mark pointed out in his comment, the "-l" in the command "Set-ADUser" was a mistake and "userWorkstations" attribute got set with invalid values. Hence AD denied access and it reflected on FBA as invalid username and password.
Ran another script to fix that attribute and all works fine now.